# Does Python have a way of returning a list without the first n elements?

Tags: python

Say I have [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]. And I want [3, 4, 5, 6].

Currently I'm doing:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
l[-(len(l) - n):]
```

I'm not familiar with Python style, but this seems pretty hack-y.

Comment: @ChristianDean why? It runs fine.

Comment: Try l[n:], then try l[-n], you will study from what you do

Comment: @vaultah Your right. My bad. I screwed up copying and pasting the OP's code into my REPL session.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, by slicing:

```
>>> n = 2
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> l[n:]
[3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Read the tutorial [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) to have a further understanding on how to manipulate Python data structures that support slicing.

Get creative and put it in a function, as mentioned in the comments:

```
def slice_it(l, n):
    return l[n:]
```

demo:

```
>>> slice_it(l, 2)
[3, 4, 5, 6]
```

And as a lambda, as shown in the comments:

```
sliced_list = lambda l, n: l[n:]
```

demo:

```
>>> sliced_list(l, 2)
[3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Or if he wants a function `first_nth = lambda lst, n: lst[n:]`.

Comment: @ChristianDean Yeah. Good plan. Added that. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! I was using slices, but every explanation I found sliced using a negative number, hence my hack-y work around.

Answer (score 1):

You can use positive int as slice lower bound:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
l[n:]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just l[n:], rather than using negative indexing with the full length of the list.

For example, if `len(l) == 6` then:

```
l[2:] == l[-4:]
```

Answer (score -1):

Keep in mind @idjaw has a much better answer,

You can also use `list comprehensions`, like so:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> n = 3
>>> l = [x + 1 for x in range(len(l)) if x >= n]
>>> l
[4, 5, 6]
```